# Angular global service

Tags: angular, typescript, singleton

I have an app in wchich I need to store global variables, that are assigned to the user. I would share it to every component, so I created Service wchich provides access to them. Is there a way to share this service everywhere in app no matter what? I know I can use [angular singleton pattern](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services), but still I need to inject this service to every component constructor in application. I would rather share this service everywhere without importing it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to avoid Dependency Injection, which is core to the Angular Framework and a very common pattern. If your reasoning is simply to avoid 'inflating' your constructors, I'd advise against it. Otherwise, you can acheive globally accessible data structures and methods by creating .ts files and using the export keyword.

E.g.

example.ts

```
export class Example {
    static dataStructure: any[];
    static someMethod(): void {};
}
```

I personally use this with enums to manage things like routes in my apps, e.g.:

```
export enum AppRoute {
    HOME = "home",
    LOGIN = "login",
    PROFILE = "user-profile"
}
```

However, you'll still need to import 'example.ts' in your components - you just won't have to create them in your constructors. Your IDE might handle that.

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

https://betterprogramming.pub/the-6-benefits-of-dependency-injection-7802b207ec69